# How to get a specific list of entries per date from a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I created a database called movies_200186807, I need to list all of the months that movies where listed in every month.

Here is my database

```
CREATE DATABASE movies_200186807;
USE movies_200186807;

CREATE TABLE movies_200186807 (
    movie_name   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    release_date DATE NOT NULL,
    cost         DEC(4) NOT NULL,
    revenue      DEC(4) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO movies_200186807 (movie_name, release_date, cost, revenue)
VALUES
    ('Toy Story', '1995-11-22',30 , 364),
    ('Toy Story 2', '1999-11-24',90 , 511),
    ('Toy Story 3', '2010-06-18', 200, 1070),
    ('A Bugs Life', '1998-11-25', 60, 363),
    ('Monsters Inc', ' 2001-11-02', 115, 560),
    ('Finding Nemo', '2003-05-30', 94, 906),
    ('The Incredibles', '2005-11-04', 92, 615),
    ('Cars', '2006-06-09', 120, 462),
    ('Cars 2', '2011-06-24', 200, 560),
    ('Ratatouille', '2007-06-29', 150, 626),
    ('Wall-E', '2008-06-27', 180, 533),
    ('Up', '2009-05-29', 175, 731),
    ('Brave', '2012-06-22', 185, 555),
    ('Monster University', '2013-06-21', 200, 744),
    ('Planes', '2013-08-09', 50, 220);
```

-- 5) List all of the months that movies where released in: Month & 
Number_Of_Movies in that month. Ex) November  = 5 movies in that month

I have done this query which does not output the number of movies in each month, it outputs each movie and day released

```
SELECT DAY(release_date), MONTHNAME(release_date)
FROM movies_200186807;
```

Any Suggestions,

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you investigated aggregate query functions such as `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that release_date is being stored as a date, try:

```
select monthname(release_date), count(*) as cnt from movies
group by month(release_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

select monthname(release_date), count(*) as num_of_movies 
from movies_200186807
group by month(release_date);

Here is the answer, thank you for your help

I changed cnt to num_of_movies and change month to monthname to get the name of the month(july) instead of the number(07).

Thank again